# How to use ResponseErrorHandler in spring mvc

Tags: java, spring-mvc

I am completely new to spring-mvc, I have developed sample project with controllers, models and exception handling like below:

```
public class MyNestableException extends NestableRuntimeException {

    /**
     * Constants
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    public static final String MESSAGE_INTERNAL_ERROR = "Internal server error";
    public static final long CODE_INTERNAL_ERROR = 500;

    private long code = 0;

    /**
     * To get an error code
     * @return long
     */
    public long getCode() {
        return code;
    }

    /**
     * To set an error code
     * @param code
     */
    public void setCode(long code) {
        this.code = code;
    }

    /**
     * @param code
     * @param message
     */
    public MYNestableException(final long code, final String message) {
        super(message);
        this.code = code;
    }

}
```

and for each block of code am catching like below

```
try {
 //code
} catch(MyNestableException e) {
  throw new MYNestableException(
                    MYNestableException.CODE_INTERNAL_ERROR,
                    "Error occured while processing GET request");
}
```

I have given this code for review at architect level , they asked me to use **spring mvc ResponseErrorHandler**

i have gone through the online resources but there is no clarity on how to call this ...

everyone is explaining just how to override this...but not explaining where to call , how to call, will it cover all exceptions ?

Can any one give me best way of using ResponseErrorHandler ?

Answer (score 0):

From the description of your problem it looks like you should be using Exception Handler facility provided by Spring MVC where you can declaratively instruct Spring MVC to return appropriate views whenever a custom exception is thrown by Controller code. For a sample usage pattern you can look [here](http://www.mkyong.com/spring-mvc/spring-mvc-exceptionhandler-example/).